# Visual Studio "Unable to start program" but is exists

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I'm running a SW solution C++ based, using MFC GUI (I know, quite old, but this is my setup).

My development platform is a Windows 7 PC, with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate development platform.
Here is my issue:

1. Building the debug solution works fine and the .exe file is generated in the right way
2. starting the SW from IDE without debugging it, works fine (so the CTRL+F5 is fine, so the output path of the build process is right and the project has been built in the right way)
3. The file has no dependency on custom dll (I built it linking to static MFC lib, and the Process Explorer when starting the process in CRTL+F5 display no dependencies)
4. When starting the debug process (F5) a MessageBox with message ("Unable to start program" "The system cannot find the file specified"), but the path in the MessageBox exists and works fine (see point 1 in the list)

Is there any way to get a detailed error message from debugger startup process?

Comment: Check the settings maybe there is some path which needs to be changed there.

Comment: could be the working directory is set incorrectly?

Comment: What would happen if you threw out the project and built a new one?

Comment: @TopologicalSort I will give it a try as soon as possible

Comment: @AlanBirtles I think that since the CTRL+F5 works fine (that is start it without debugging), the path setup is right. I checked the whole set of paths and it seems to be fine